# I have a built in deep fryer outside. Is it safe to leave oil in it

Tags: deep-frying

I have a commercial grade built in deep fryer that I put in my outdoor kitchen.  I have been using it for awhile now and I just leave the oil in the fryer and put a stainless steel cover on it.  The oil looks to be in good shape not dark or anything and the food taste good.  The oil doesn’t smell or anything like that.   I will use the fryer once a week and change the oil every 2-3 months.  Is this a safe and healthy way of storing the oil?  Draining the oil after every use is not ideal as there is a lot of it.   Would like anyone’s input if possible.  Thanks

Comment: If you're in a humid area, with significant changes in temperature during the day, you might want to do something to make sure you're not going to have condensation on the lid that would drip into the oil ... it might make for a nasty surprise when you heat it back up.  (not speaking from experience, other than a grease fire)

Comment: Yes we are in a humid area but it feels cooler under the covered cabana and we are in northern florida so not as bad as south florida.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that your fryer is protected from the elements, the safety issues for an outdoor fryer are the same as for an indoor one. Fryer oil can be used over and over again. It absolutely does not need to be to be changed every use. Restaurants that use fryers a lot will filter the oil on a daily or near daily basis, but even oil that gets used a lot doesn't get changed daily. Changing the oil is not a matter of safety. While there is some minor long-term health risk associated with eating oil that is past its peak quality, it's not an immediate food safety issue. Since you use your fryer only about once a week, it should be fine for three months perhaps filtering it two or three times. Even the filtering is for quality purposes only, pathogens cannot survive in fryer oil.

The bottom line is that oil that still tastes good is fine to use.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply it makes me feel a lot better.   The deep fryer is protected from the elements under a cabana and I have a stainless steel lid on it.

Comment: One more thing Jolenealaska it seems you know a lot about fryer oil.  I am currently using corn oil and my wife says that isn't the healthiest oil to be using.   What is the best oil that I should be using that is somewhat healthy?

Comment: @AdamJohnson I know nothing of healthy as it relates to fryer oil. I do know that for taste quality, peanut oil is pretty much the gold standard. Or peanut oil plus beef tallow for a certain kind of connoisseur.

Comment: Yes I know about peanut oil but I have neighbors that is allergic to peanuts and corn.   I am currently using corn oil but I want to switch to something else.

Comment: Vegetable (soybean) oil, rice bran oil, and safflower oil are all good. If money is no object, avocado oil may be best.

Comment: Pure beef tallow is the way to go if you want the best taste IMNSHO. @Jolenealaska  **;-) :-) ;-)**